# Privacy and GrapheneOS

Tags: privacy, phone

I am planning to purchase Google Pixel 7 Pro assuming that the Pixel lineup will continue to be the device of choice for GrapheneOS developers.

Here are some of the constraints that I have to work with:

1. I need to continue using the postpaid phone service. Yes, I
   understand that my phone number and all kinds of collected data will be
   tied to my identity.
2. I need a map application/service that at least has "all" of the
   street names and numbers. That will probably be the only non-FOSS
   app that I will have to install unless I will ever be forced to use
   some specific authenticator app that can only be downloaded from the
   Google Play Store.

Here are my questions:

1. My first concern is figuring out the most private way to obtain the
   phone. Many people suggest purchasing a device from a private
   reseller (Eg. eBay). I don't mind doing so. However, if I purchase
   the device outside of my carrier or Google and immediately put
   GrapheneOS on it, will my service provider still be able to connect
   the phone's IMEI (or perhaps other important info) to my identity
   once I insert the SIM and connect to their network?
2. How to minimize cellular tracking? Here is what GrapheneOS had to say about that:
   https://grapheneos.org/faq#cellular-tracking  Given that paragraph,
   is turning on the airplane mode on Graphene OS equivalent to putting
   the phone in a faraday bag (solely for the purposes of cellular
   tracking)? In other words, are there any concerns on the firmware
   level that GrapheneOS wouldn't be able to address?
3. The convenience of knowing the
   location/reviews of businesses on Apple/Google maps is great, but I
   can definitely live without it. I truly wish I could use OSM, but
   the lack of street numbers and sometimes even names make it
   unusable, as information like that is a bare minimum for me. (That
   is the case, at least in my area.) Fortunately, I can have Google
   Maps sandboxed on GrapheneOS. Furthermore, Google Maps allow users
   to download maps for offline usage. Given that I can run them in a
   sandbox and (assuming that I can) take away their privilege to
   connect to the internet, how private is that option? It makes sense
   that, at some point, the app might request to connect to the
   internet for updates. If I allow that, it will have a chance to
   report all of the logged activity. Any assessment of this situation
   would be much appreciated along with any suggestions to implement
   this better.

Comment: This question and very broad and I don't think this is the right place to ask for such product specific questions. I recommend that you ask the [GrapheneOS community](https://grapheneos.org/contact) instead.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will do so.

Comment: @Vladimir for the maps application there is actually a FOSS solution: it's called Organic Maps.

Comment: @SirMuffington Thank you for the suggestion, but Organic Maps uses data from OSM (OpenStreetMap). The issue is that in my area, most of the streets are completely missing numbers. If I am in a time crunch and need a navigation to a specific spot on a long boulevard, that would be a major issue.